# AWSSimpleSystemsManagement describeParameters returns only one parameter at a time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to fetch the list of parameters from AWS which start with a certain prefix. I could not figure out how to get all the parameters.

```
ParametersFilter filter = 
 new ParametersFilter().
 withKey("Name").
 withValues("vyom"); // the key prefix i want

DescribeParametersRequest request = 
  new DescribeParametersRequest().withFilters(filter);

AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client =
  AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();

DescribeParametersResult result = 
  client.
    describeParameters(request);

List<ParameterMetadata> params =    
  result.
  getParameters(); // returns a list of size one
```

The `DescribeParametersResult` always has the `nextToken` set, and calling the client again, with the next token returns the next parameter.

Invoking aws cli from the terminal returns all parameters as i expected.
`aws ssm describe-parameters --filters "Key=Name,Values=vyom"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same problem; it seems to be working as designed. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeParameters.html):

> Request results are returned on a best-effort basis. If you specify MaxResults in the request, the response includes information up to the limit specified. The number of items returned, however, can be between zero and the value of MaxResults. If the service reaches an internal limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns the matching values up to that point and a NextToken. You can specify the NextToken in a subsequent call to get the next set of results.

That is to say: the filtering is applied *after* the paging. If I set `MaxResults` to 50, then the first page returns filtered results from the first 50 parameters visible in the console UI, the second page returns results from the second 50 parameters and so on... the CLI just does the job of iterating through the pages for you.

The next problem you're going to run into once you start paging through the results is the aggressive throttling. There's some good discussion [here](https://github.com/segmentio/chamber/issues/76), including the gem:

> Obviously the best solution would be to increase the AWS rate-limits, but they seem very unwilling to do that for DescribeParameters (they insist that it should only be used for manual querying on a CLI).

Godspeed!